# How to use CiviCRM Webform to process CiviCRM fields at each step rather than on submit?

Tags: webform-civicrm, activities

Use case:

A multi step CiviCRM Drupal web form where I want any CiviCRM fields and CiviCRM activities to be updated in CiviCRM as each step is completed rather than only at the end of the completed form.

This enables 2 things:

1. Data in an uncompleted form is still captured in CiviCRM.
2. Progress through the form can be tracked via CiviCRM activities so that CiviCRM smart groups can be created to mail/remind specific users to complete the rest of the form.

Is this possible? If not, would others be interested in it?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a couple of times now using a custom drupal module and hooks.  You can get data into civicrm using the api.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the required by daisy-chaining a number of separate webforms (using webform checksum to pass the same contact id through each form). You would need to change the 'submit' button to be eg 'next page' - and going backwards might be hard but not impossible - but it would allow for Activities etc to be triggered at each step.